# How to create index for ReferenceField mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, pymongo, mongoengine

I want to create index for `ReferenceField` so the query can work faster, but I don't know how to do it with `mongoengine` by defining that in the class `meta` property:

Here's the `Post` Document code I have written:

```py
class Post(Document):
  slug = StringField(max_length=60, required=True)
  content = StringField(required=True)
  user_id = ReferenceField(document_type='User', dbref=True, required=True)
  published_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, required=True)
  updated_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, required=True)

  meta = {
    'collection': 'social_posts',
    'indexes': [
      'user_id.$id'
    ]
  }
```

When I try to create index for `user_id.$id` which is the way `ReferenceField` is stored in the `mongodb`, throws the below error:

```
mongoengine.errors.LookUpError: Cannot perform join in mongoDB: user_id__$id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the index to a ReferenceField in mongoengine you just need to specify the name of the field - without the suffix `.$id`.

So your code would be like that:

```
meta = {
'collection': 'social_posts',
'indexes': [
  'user_id'
]
}
```

Mongoengine creates the index on the id of the references automatically, even if it is a a DBRef.

Comment: keep in mind that mongoengine will send a create_index every time you want to insert an element into the collection. If you have N indexes, you will have N+1 requests to the DB

Answer (score 3):

Please be careful when creating indexes with MongoEngine. By default, the library always tries to create an index **every time you insert something**. Index creation in MongoDB is a blocking expensive operation that causes performance issues.

You should always avoid it. My suggestion is to do the following

```
import mongoengine as me

class MongoModel(me.Document):

    some_field = me.StringField()
    other_field = me.StringField()

    meta = {
        "auto_create_index": False,
        "index_background": True,
        "indexes": [
            "other_field",
        ]
    }
```

and them having a separated command to run the index creation as you would do in any other database

Comment: Although it is true that it is trying to recreate the index in some cases, it isn't True that it does it on every insert, it only creates the indexes once (per thread) when the Model underlying collection is triggered (e.g when calling Document.objects() or when calling .save() the first time). (mongoengine contributor here)